# Creating floating frames near a link, which opens on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create a GreaseMonkey script which creates a floating frame near links (with relevant content), in a similar way to [Google's instant search](http://www.google.com/landing/instantpreviews/#a). The frame should be drag-able and close-able, with HTML content in it (possibly from URLs). It should be something like small window, and not built in frame like `<iframe>`.

If I can make the box pop up only when some kind of button is pushed (like the magnifying glass button on Google's instant search) it will be even better.

Is it possible to do it with JavaScript (or HTML, or other), or is there an open lib which does that (like the `<button class="vspib">`from Google's instant search)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's [jLinkPreview](http://www.sarpdoruktahmaz.com/projects/j-link-preview/) for jQuery.